# Agrupar chaves de um array

Tags: php, array

Como agrupar chaves e valores idênticos de um array?

Podem existir N arrays dentro do array, não pode adicionar chaves iguais.

Por exemplo:

```
 [attributes] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [title] => Cor
                [type] => text
                [values] => Array
                    (
                        [1] => Amarelo
                    )

            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [title] => Cor
                [type] => text
                [values] => Array
                    (
                        [2] => Azul
                    )

            )
        [2] => Array
            (
                [title] => Largura
                [type] => text
                [values] => Array
                    (
                        [2] => Grande
                    )

            )
```

Resultado desejado:

```
 [attributes] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [title] => Cor
                [type] => text
                [values] => Array
                    (
                        [1] => Amarelo
                        [2] => Azul
                    )

            )
        [2] => Array
            (
                [title] => Largura
                [type] => text
                [values] => Array
                    (
                        [2] => Grande
                    )

            )
```

Comment: Qual é a dificuldade? Não estou a entender.

Comment: Fazer dinâmicamente, sendo que o array pode mudar, preciso agrupar somente quando o `title` e `type` forem iguais, cor e largura são exemplos, mas pode vir qualquer valor, quando iguais, agrupar os `values`.

Comment: Fazes uma função de inserir no `array`, que compare o `title` com os já existentes e se houver um igual acrescenta ao `values`

Comment: É aí que tô apanhando rsrrsrsrsrs, travei nisso. rs

Comment: És tu que crias o array certo?

Comment: Não, vem do BD, pode ter 0 ou 1000 resultados.

Comment: É complicadito fazer isso sem consumir grandes recursos... Quando chegar a casa vejo.

Comment: Então, parecia simples quando olhei. rs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não é uma grande solução, porque se a array for muito grande, demora muito tempo. Digamos que é quase uma gambiarra, porque para usar esta solução e seu problema deve ser profundo.

```
$atrib = Array(
        0 => Array
            (
                "title" => "Cor",
                "type" => "text",
                "values" => Array
                    (
                        1 => "Amarelo"
                    )),
        1 => Array
            (
                "title" => "Cor",
                "type" => "text",
                "values" => Array
                    (
                        2 => "Azul"
                    )),
        2 => Array
            (
                "title" => "Largura",
                "type" => "text",
                "values" => Array
                    (
                        2 => "Grande"
                    )));


foreach ($atrib as &$A_value) {
    foreach ($atrib as $key=> $B_value) {
        if($A_value['title']==$B_value['title'])
        {
            if($A_value['values']!=$B_value['values'])
            {
                $A_value['values'] = array_merge($A_value['values'],$B_value['values']);
                unset($atrib[$key]);
            }

        }


    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$array3[] = '';
$array3[] = array("bola", "quadrado", "triangulo");
$array3[] = array("esfera", "quadrado", "triangulo");

$result1 = array_diff($array3[1], $array3[2]);
$result2 = array_diff($array3[2], $array3[1]);

$full = array_merge($result1, $result2);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($array3);
echo '<Hr>';
print_r($full);
echo '<Hr>';
//print_r($array2);
unset($array3[0]);
unset($array3[1]);
array_unshift($array3, $full);

print_r($array3);

?>
```

Comment: ops... sempre serão 3 índices esse array?

Comment: se for coloca $array[0], $array[1] / $array[1], $array[0]

Comment: Cara, é um único array, com vários arrays internos, que possuem outro array, não funciona da mesma forma, o padrão é exatamente o que coloquei na pergunta.

Comment: uai compara o array[1] com array[0]

Comment: testa aê, talvez tenha te compreendido errado, mas aqui não funciona.

Comment: testa com o exemplo que te dei, com string seria tranquilo, mas tenta com array dentro de array.

Comment: refiz ele com array dentro de array

Comment: @MarceloAymone, entao testa ai editei dinovo... ve se e isso

Comment: ou teras que fazer o que o marcelo bb falow

Comment: Sim, mas meu array traz até 100 arrays dentro dele, e em outras situações apenas 4 ou 5, como faria? tem que ser dinâmico.

Comment: entao e melhor vc criar uma função que vrifica o que existe no array... e depois adicionar o conteudo ... pq se nao vai ter que da muita volta pra organizar esse array

Comment: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/ref.array.php da uma olhada ai tem função que verifica o que tem dentro do array... ai fica facin